# HashMap in hibernate contains himself

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I have entity, and I want to add field which is hashMap contains himself and number of occurrences

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Map<MyClass, Integer> myClassRelation = new HashMap<MyClass, Integer>();
    ....
}
```

I want to reach following result: I want to have some collection which can contains set of class MyClass inner of class MyClass, and I want to have possibility to add duplicates to this collection. I tried to reach that using ArrayList, but when I added duplicate:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<MyClass> myClassRelation = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    ....
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
//add the same object 2 times
myOterClass.getMyClassRelation().add(myClass);
myOterClass.getMyClassRelation().add(myClass);
```

and then I have following error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__FORMULAR__058FE285EB0330EE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
```

How can I add the same object many times to this collection. Which collection type I should use?

Comment: Show the full MyClass class. Seems like you either have a ID or a Unique Constraint.

Comment: yes, I have:   @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "f_id", nullable = false)
 private long id;  and so what? I don't create many times the same element. I add existing element (MyClass myClass = new MyClass();) to the list

Answer (score 0):

You have a Reflexive Relationship which means. Your MyClass is related to your MyClass.

```
MyClass 1 --> * MyClass
```

So when you do the following

```
myOterClass.getMyClassRelation().add(myClass);
myOterClass.getMyClassRelation().add(myClass);
```

You are trying to add the same value twice. Because `MyClass` has only one Table.

Comment: So, how can I reach desribed relation. I have to have possibility to add to array duplicates. I created Map which contains myClass and number of occurences, but as I said in first post, there are errors which using OneToMany annotation with map. Any ideas?